# Print "n" results of a function "n" times

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to print out a sort of pyramid. User inputs an integer value 'i', and that is displayed i-times.

Like if input=5

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

I have tried this:

```
input=5
for i in range(input+1):
    print("i"*i)
    i=i+1
```

The result of which is

```
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
```

The problem is that (as far as I know), only a string can be printed out 'n' times, but if I take out the inverted commas around "i", it becomes (i*i) and gives out squares:

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

Is there a simple way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your `int` loop varaible to `str` before building the output string by multiplying:

```
input = 5
for i in range(1, input+1):
    print(str(i) * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = 5
for i in range(a): # <-- this causes i to go from 0,1,2,3,...,a-1
    print("{}".format(i+1)*(i+1)) # < -- this creates a new string in each iteration ; an alternative would be str(i+1)*(i+1)
    i=i+1 # <-- this is unnecessary, i already goes from 0 to a-1 and will be re-created in the next iteration of the loop.
```

This creates a new string in each iteration of the loop. 
Note that `for i in range(a)` will go through the range by itself. There is no need to additionally increment i at the end. In general it is considered bad practise to change indices you loop over.

Comment: @DavidBuck I completely agree. Tried to keep it as close to op's question, and may have made a mistake on the way. Everything aside, input is not a great name for a variable.